# Proving height function is Morse

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, morse-theory

We have a differentiable manifold $X$ **embedded** in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and let $h: X \to \mathbb{R}$ as $h(x_{1},...,x_{n+1})=x_{n+1}$. We need to prove that $h$ is a Morse function.

I don't know how to prove this: my idea was to calculate the derivative $dh_{x}$, doing a parametrization $\phi:U \rightarrow X$ of $X$ around x and see what $d(h\circ\phi)_{x}$ and $d \phi^{-1}_{x}$ are.
But I have no idea besides this.
Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please specify what $X$ is, because for general $X$ the function $h$ need not be morse (take $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ embedded via $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto (x_1, \ldots, x_n, 0)$ so that $h$ is constant).

Comment: It's essentially circular. The height function is not necessarily a Morse function. It is Morse if at each critical point, the Hessian is nondegenerate. On the other hand, the Hessian at a critical point of a height function is the second fundamental form. It follows that a height function is a Morse function if and only if at each critical point of $h$, the second fundamental form is nondegenerate.

Comment: Oh really? I think I forgot something then, X is an manifold **embedded** in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: I'm not sure whose comment you're referring to. The assumption here is that $X$ is embedded. The height function of an embedded submanifold of codimension $1$ is not necessarily Morse. As @BenSteffan points out, the horizontal hyperplane is a counterexample. For a compact counterexample, take, say, the sphere and flatten out the top of it. In particular, it is important to note that the definition of a Morse function is a condition on the **second** derivatives of $h$ and not just the first derivatives.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for misleading you then, I was reading a pdf that said this, without proof and thought it would be true. If it isn´t too much of a bother, would you help me to know if the height function restricted to the set $\{(x,y,z): 4x^2+y^2+z^2=5 $ and $ z >1 \} $ is morse or not? Thank you so much for your answers @Deane and Ben Steffan!

Comment: No problem. I’ll assume you want the height function to be $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$. You can find the first and second derivatives of $z$ by implicit differentiation. You use these equations to figure out where the critical points are and what the Hessian of $z$ is at each of those points.

Comment: My answer isn’t quite right. We want to view the height function as a function of the surface. The critical points are where the tangent plane is horizontal. This implies that in a neighborhood of a critical point, the surface is a graph of the height function. Now you can view $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ and proceed as above.

Comment: Ok, I used implicit differentiation to find $4x+z z_{x}=0$ and $y+z z_{y}=0$, so the critical points which are where $(z_{x},z_{y})=(0,0)$ (right?), would be are $x=0$, $y=0$. Is this correct?